Jest error - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
whenever i run jest test i get the following error
I tried to explicitly add /node_modules/@azure/logger to testPathIgnorePatterns but it still throws error.
jest.config
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/__mocks__/', '/e2e/'],
  testEnvironment: './jest.environment.ts',

jest.environment
const Environment = require('jest-environment-jsdom').default;

module.exports = class CustomTestEnvironment extends Environment {
  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    this.global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
    this.global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
    this.global.Response = Response;
    this.global.Request = Request;
  }
};

Error
/node_modules/@azure/logger/dist/browser/index.js:3
    import debug from "./debug.js";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

